# Quantity Update broken on basket page

Tags: quantity, magento1.9.3

I have just been fixing **1.9.3.4** with the **formkey** code into my Theme's billing and shipping code pages. That has mostly restored the functionality with respect to those with Form Key security turned on.

However, the Update Quantity functionality is broken. Entering a new Qty fails to change it to the new value. This is on the main Cart page

```
<site>/index.php/checkout/cart/
```

The Update Qty feature on the Basket Pull down (**top right**), does work properly.

Hope you can help.

Brian

Comment: This is broken at the top level of the store also. Adding more than 1 item fails. Quantity stays at 1

Answer (score 0):

I had two issues:

1. Needed to add

   varien/product_options.js
   to catalogue.xml in the theme (in all three labels)
2. Needed to set non-secure base url also as https: to avoid mixed content.

Brian